# Test until success using rxjava2

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

What is the correct way to implement the tests below using rxjava2?

Given a list of ntp servers, test each one until you succeed.

Example:

- time.nist.gov -> timeout
- pool.ntp.org -> timeout
- time.google.com -> success, get date
- time.apple.com -> ignore

I do not want to test all in parallels but one by one. And if all fail, it restarts the test again.

Using only one server, the code I'm using is this:

```java
public void getTime() {
    timeObservable = Observable
            .fromCallable(new Callable<Date>() {
                @Override
                public Date call() throws IOException {
                    return connectAndGetTime(HOST);
                }
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnError(new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(Throwable error) {
                    Timber.tag(TAG).e(error);
                }
            })
            .retry(5);

    timeObservable.subscribe(new Consumer<Date>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(Date date) {
            mDate = date;
        }
    }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(Throwable throwable) {
            Timber.tag(TAG).e(throwable);
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think since you want to try different hosts sequentially, you need not to use rxJava at all. Just write a loop with several connectAndGetTime() inside.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Alexei, you're right.
Why complicate things?

The end result looks like this:

```java
public void getTime() {
    timeObservable = Observable
            .fromCallable(new Callable<Date>() {
                @Override
                public Date call() {
                    for (String host : Arrays.asList("time.google.com", "time.apple.com", "time.nist.gov")) {
                        try {
                            return connectAndGetTime(host);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Timber.tag(TAG).d("Sync (%s) fail!", host);
                        }
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnError(new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(Throwable error) {
                    Timber.tag(TAG).e(error);
                }
            })
            .retry(5);

    timeObservable.subscribe(new Consumer<Date>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(Date date) {
            mDate = date;
        }
    }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(Throwable throwable) {
            Timber.tag(TAG).e(throwable);
        }
    });
}
```